# Struggling to style div with html / css in react app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Since I'm learning html/css I'm working and making some examples, and I want to create a div which would look like this, but my content is 'glued' together.

I've tried varios ways and noone of them is near this, since I'm really new to html / css!

If you run code below you might see it looks bad, there is no space between texts, nothing is vertically aligned, and I don't know how to position size to the middle of div.

Here is my code :

```
<div style={{ background: '#e1e1e1', marginBottom: '5px' }}>
  <span id="delete" style={{ float: 'right', display: 'inline-block', padding: '2px 5px' }}>
    x
  </span>
  <i className="icon ion-md-checkmark-circle" />
  TestImg1.PNG
  3.98KB
</div>
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this with explanation how it's done so I might learn a lot from it. 
Thanks and cheers!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap's grid system instead.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-grey align-items-center">
    <div class="col-2">
    <i class="material-icons icon-green">
        check_circle
    </i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      File.png
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      52kb
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      x
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Maro94/nmezduhy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize Flexbox to handle the layout and ordering of your elements. Set `display: flex` on the parent `<div>`. Define the ordering of your elements using the ordering property with one being the first and three being the last. After that, assign `margin-left: auto;` to the delete element to push it to the end of the parent `<div>`. You can see the code rendered here: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/rNVBEpP)

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', background: '#e1e1e1', marginBottom: '5px', padding: '2px 5px' }}>
    <span id="delete" style={{ order: '3', marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
        x
    </span>
    <i className="icon ion-md-checkmark-circle" style={{ order: '1' }} />
    <span style={{ order: '2', marginRight: '10px' }}>
        TestImg1.PNG 3.98KB
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **Flex**.

```
<div style={{ background: '#e1e1e1', marginBottom: '5px', display:flex }}>
  <I style={{flex: 0}} className="icon ion-md-checkmark-circle" />
  <span style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: 8px}}>
    TestImg1.PNG
  </span>
  <span style={{flex: 1}}>
    3.98KB
  </span>
  <span id="delete" style={{ flex: 0, padding: '2px 5px' }}>
    x
  </span>
</div>
```

`display: flex` is applied to the container.

`flex: 1` applied to texts and it means **automatically stretch with ratio 1.**

`flex: 0` applied to icons and it means **don't stretch.**

If you want to learn more, take a look at [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I've tried this code but icon circle is next to TestImg1 I will edit my post to show you how it looks.  I've edited my post, check please.

Comment: I also forgot to apply the style to the icon element. Edited.

Comment: still glue after adding flex:0 to icon.. and is it possible to increase height?

Comment: For the glue issue just give some margin to either icon or text.

Comment: and if I add height to parent div all items are not centered anymore, how is that?

Comment: If you want a vertically centered, add this to your container style: `align-items: center`. And take a look at the reference in the bottom of the answer to learn more about flexbox.